# Валидация формы обратной связи php

Tags: php, валидация

У меня есть простенький php скрипт который отправляет сообщение в чат телеграмм от имени бота. На сайте есть форма обратной связи к которой подключен данный php обработчик.

Мне нужно сделать так что-бы нельзя было отправить пустые поля! Как мне это сделать?

Сам код:

sendmess.php

```
<?php

/* https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getUpdates,
где, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - токен вашего бота, полученный ранее */

$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$token = "TOKEN_BOT";
$chat_id = "CHAT_ID";
$arr = array(
  'ФИО:' => $name,
  'Email:' => $email,
  'Телефон:' => $phone,
);


foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>" . urlencode($key) . " </b>" . urlencode($value) ."%0A";
};

$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

if ($sendToTelegram) {
  header('Location: index.php');
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
?>
```

index.php

```
          <!-- Форма обратной связи -->
          <form action="sendmess.php" method="POST">

            <!-- Каждый input для выравнивания вкладываем в блок input-box -->
            <div class="input-box">
              <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="ФИО" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
              <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
              <input type="phone" name="user_phone" placeholder="Телефон" />
            </div>
            <div class="button">
              <input class="button" type="submit" value="Отправить" />
            </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы проверить заполнение формы в браузере, можно добавить атрибут [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) к каждому обязательному полю, примерно так:

```
<input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="ФИО" required="" />
```

А чтобы наличие данных проверил сервер, в PHP подойдут [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty) и [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var):

```
if (
    // empty вернёт true для пустой строки, отсутствующего значения и прочего такого, что нам не надо
    empty($_POST['user_name'])
    || empty($_POST['user_email'])
    || empty($_POST['user_phone'])
    // а это проверка правильности заполнения email
    || filter_var($_POST['user_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false
) {
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: empty() не стоит использовать, эта функция занимается подавлением ошибок.  В данном случае вместо `empty($_POST['user_name'])` лучше написать `!$_POST['user_name']` или `strlen($_POST['user_name']) === 0`. Эффект тот же, но если программист допустит ошибку в коде формы, то РНР сможет помочь найти её. Но в идеале конечно должна быть нормальная валидация.

Comment: @Ипатьев Но empty для валидации же  лучше. Мы же точно знаем, что с формы должно прийти. Получается, что без этой функции надо проверить вначале переменную на существование, а потом на не пустоту, что сразу делает empty...

Comment: @Pashok так часто делают, но вообще это халтура. Тут надо скорее проверить отправку формы целиком, а наличие полей если и проверять, то именно что отдельно: поле отсутствует или есть но пустое - это две разные ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Главное, о чем забыли все комментаторы - это *юзабилити*. Удобство пользователя. Возможность не вбивать заново уже введенные данные в случае ошибки.

Ну и плюс соблюдение базовых стандартов.

Весь код, приведенный ниже, представляет собой один файл, разбитый на отдельные фрагменты только чтобы убрать вертикальный скролл.

Предполагается, что код целиком находится в файле sendmess.php. Чтобы форма была отдельно, пример надо будет переделывать либо на AJAX, либо на использование сессий (заодно решив и проблему вывода сообщения об успешной отправке).

В целом мне кажется, что код легко читается и не нуждается в подробных комментариях.

Сначала идут настройки скрипта и инициализация

```
<?php

$token = "TOKEN_BOT";
$chat_id = "CHAT_ID";
// задаем массив полей, 
// который будет использоваться для валидации, создания сообщения и вывода формы
$fields = [
    'user_name' => 'ФИО',
    'user_email' => 'Email',
    'user_phone' => 'Телефон',
];

$errors = [];
// инициализируем массив $input чтобы выводить values в форме до отправки
$input = array_fill_keys(array_keys($fields), '');
```

Затем идет проверка на отправку формы, и её обработка

```
if ($_POST) {
    $txt = '';
    foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
        $var = trim($_POST[$key]);
        if(strlen($var) === 0) {
            $errors[] = "Не заполнено поле $value";
        } else {
            $input[$key] = $var;
            $txt .= "<b>$key:</b>$var<br />\n";
        }
    }

    if (!$errors) {
        $query = http_build_query([
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'parse_mode' => 'html',
            'text' => $txt,
        ]);
        $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?$query";
        if (file_get_contents($url) !== false) {
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            $errors[] = "Временная ошибка, повторите позднее";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

и далее вывод формы и ошибок.

```
<?php foreach($errors as $error): ?>
    <?= htmlspecialchars($error) ?><br />
<?php endforeach ?>

<!-- Форма обратной связи -->
<form method="POST">
  <!-- Каждый input для выравнивания вкладываем в блок input-box -->
  <?php foreach($fields as $key => $value): ?>
  <div class="input-box">
    <input 
      type="text"
      name="<?= htmlspecialchars($key) ?>"
      placeholder="<?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?>"
      value="<?= htmlspecialchars($input[$key]) ?>"
      required
    />
  </div>
  <?php endforeach ?>
  <div class="button">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Отправить" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Здесь мы позаботились и о пользователе, и о программисте, снабдив каждого удобными сообщениями об ошибках, и заполнив форму ранее введенными значениями.

Answer (score -1):

- Немного отрефакторил код, по другому не могу.
- `"` заменил на `'` так подстановкки не подразумеваются
- переименовал переменную
- `$txt` заранее не была создана, это не критично, но и не приветствуется
- массив объявил в более современном виде через `[...]`
- foreach заменил на `array_map`, теперь `$txt` не нужна
- конкатенацию заменил на sprintf чтобы сделать строку короче
- дополнительно проверил на строку, так как в `$POST` могут передать массив
- убрал лишние возможные пробелы с помошью `trim`
- убрал элементы массива строго равные пустой строке
- И другое ...

*Обычный `array_filter` работает через empty, что может неочевидно убрать строку равную нулю `$string = '0';`*

**sendmess.php**

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use JetBrains\PhpStorm\NoReturn;

if (!array_key_exists('REQUEST_METHOD', $_SERVER)) {
    echo 'This script only for server usage!';
    die();
}

const SERVER = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot';
const TOKEN = '6437088323:AAHtGDi42VPoYQf88OlPZzBCL6VoEfMU3og';
# Public channel https://t.me/qwertsxfgdfg
const CHAT_ID = '-1001958240606';

match ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    default => processOther(),
    'GET' => processGet(),
    'POST' => processPost(),
};

function processGet(): void {
    require_once 'index.php';
}

#[NoReturn]
function processOther(): void {
    echo 'Only GET or POST methods allowed!';
    die();
}

function processPost(): void {
    try {
        if (!fopen(getUrl(), 'r')) {
            die('Error.');
        }
    } catch (Throwable) {
        die('Exception.');
    }
    echo <<<HTML
<a href="/">
    <button>
        Success! Send again >
    </button>
</a>
HTML;
}

function getUrl(): string {
    $text = prepareMessage([
        'ФИО' => 'user_name',
        'Email' => 'user_email',
        'Телефон' => 'user_phone',
    ]);
    $buildQuery = http_build_query([
        'chat_id' => CHAT_ID,
        'text' => $text,
        'parse_mode' => 'markdown',
    ]);
    return SERVER . TOKEN . '/sendMessage?' . $buildQuery;
}

function prepareMessage($assoc): string {
    $data = array_map(fn($key) => $_POST[$key] ?? null, $assoc);
    # Массив также можно передать методом POST, но нам нужны только строки.
    $onlyStrings = array_filter($data, 'is_string');
    $trimmedStrings = array_map('trim', $onlyStrings);
    # array_filter без колбэка работает как empty и уберёт строки = '0'
    $validator = fn($value) => $value !== '';
    $filtered = array_filter($trimmedStrings, $validator);
    $processLine = function ($key) use ($filtered) {
        return sprintf('*%s*: %s', $key, $filtered[$key]);
    };
    $lines = array_map($processLine, array_keys($filtered));
    $text = implode(PHP_EOL, $lines);
    if (strlen($text) > 4000) {
        die('<a href="/">Text must be less than 4k symbols.</a>');
    }
    return $text;
}
```

- Произвёл рефакторинг
- Добавил required для input
- Добавил label так как это рекомендуется

**index.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <style>
        .label-text {
            min-width: 77px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/src/server.php" method="POST">
    <div class="input-box">
        <label>
            <span class="label-text">
                ФИО:
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="ФИО" required>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <label>
            <span class="label-text">
                Почта:
            </span>
            <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <label>
            <span class="label-text">
                Телефон:
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="user_phone" placeholder="Телефон" required>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Можно легко установить и проверить. 
Репозиторий: https://github.com/makhnanov/php8.2-simple-telegram-personal-form/tree/main

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Понял, хорошо. Спасибо!

Comment: Забавно, когда люди заботясь о стиле, меняют одни кавычки на другие, но при этом добавляют нечитаемую конструкцию на 150 отступов.  Строку мы сократили, но горизонтальный скролл при этом увеличили - гениальное улучшение :)))

Comment: Но главное, конечно, что задача решена неправильно. Надо было не "убрать пустые поля", а сделать так, чтобы с пустыми вообще не отправлялось.

Comment: @Ипатьев Спасибо за замечания. Исправил код.

Comment: @Ипатьев Что произойдёт в Вашем коде, если $_POST[$key] не будет существовать?

Comment: @RomanBakirov PHP проинформирует программиста об этом, чтобы он мог исправить ошибку.

Comment: @Ипатьев Мне, кажется, лучше сразу не создавать ошибок. И не советовать создавать ошибки.

Comment: Давайте лучше обратимся к вашему коду. Вы ключи бы убрали из репозитория. Как-то это совсем смотрится... непрофессионально. Например, описанным [тут](https://qna.habr.com/answer?answer_id=2354410#answers_list_answer) способом.

Comment: И уж тем более ваш подход с **подавлением ошибок** никуда не годится. Как и многие начинающие, вы путаете обработку ошибок с заметанием их под ковёр. Такой подход очень привлекателен поначалу, но потом очень сильно бьёт по голове. Вам надо учиться не подавлять ошибки, а позволить РНР информировать о них программиста. Ваш код молча проглотит ситуацию, если  $_POST[$key] не будет существовать, и отправит неполное сообщение. Это поведение, которое неудобно как для программиста, так и для владельца сайта.

Comment: Опять же,  die('Exception.'); За что вы так не любите программиста? Зачем лишаете его подробного и детального сообщения об ошибке, отделываясь невразумительным "Excepnion"? И что программист, по-вашему, должен делать, увидев это сообщение? Какую ошибку исправлять? Повторюсь, вы путаете обработку ошибок с их подавлением. Сообщения об ошибках никогда нельзя подавлять или подменять невнятными огрызками. Программист всегда должен быть проинформирован обо всех возникающих ошибках, без исключения.

Comment: В целом у вас получился очень стилистически неровный код. Видно, что вы пытались написать "красиво", но это сыграло с вами злую шутку. Все эти аннотации и намеки на роутинг смотрятся диковато рядом с `die()`, `echo <<<HTML` и суперглобальной магией. Если хочется сделать SOLIDно, то не стоит останавливаться на полумерах. Функцию prepareMessage желательно разбить минимум на две, и передавать в неё исходные данные явно, а не получать внутри из воздуха. Ну и четко отделить бизнес-логику, от логики отображения.